# How to get date as 2013 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

**I need to get the dates dynamically from javascript**

For eg:
i am declaring the variables below

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var prevDate = new Date();
var longDate = new Date();
```

//i am hardcoding the timeperiod, since it is coming dynamically

```
var timePeriod = "6";
```

I am getting the 2014 year in below

```
prevDate = new Date(prevDate.setMonth((-1 * parseInt(timePeriod))));
```

Now i need to get the year as 2013 and 2012

**How to do it??**

I have created fiddle to give some idea

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7q1Lvq8x/3/)

**Edit**

the  scenario is that I am working on a chart where i want 3 years data to display.

I need to get the date and parse into time period.

it looks easy, but it is not??
Can anyone please help me.

Any help is appreciated.

Please let me know If any other ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Is it so hard to google?

Comment: well, i tried but not got the answers properly @ Robo Robok

Comment: You need to get the same date but with different year? eg. today is 24/2/2015 and u need 24/2/2013 passing "2013" in input?

Comment: Is it `console.log(new Date(new Date().setFullYear(2013)));` what you are looking for?

Comment: Why are you creating a new Date object when you already have one? `prevDate.setMonth(prevDate.getMonth() - parseInt(timePeriod));`

Comment: i dont know little about javascript @  CBroe, is there any otherway can i achieve this??

Comment: can i achieve dynamically by your idea @  Matteo Rubini

Comment: Why do you put a space after `@`? That prevents notifications from working. You've been here for over a year and have more than 170 posts, so you should know how Stack Overflow works, by now.

Comment: _"Now i need to get the year as 2013 and 2012"_ This is an entirely meaningless and vacuous statement. What year? What does it mean to get a year "as" some other years? Why those years? You need to tell us precisely what it is that you are trying to accomplish. Not this vague, ambiguous, wiffle-waffle. Perhaps list inputs and desired outputs? Then show your implementation and explain how it's not doing what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to archive. May be, you can use **getFullYear** function to get the year and then apply your programming logic.

```
<script>
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getFullYear();
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can set the year like this:

```
longDate.setYear(2013)
```

or you can pass any negative number to setMonth or setYear to bring the time back to the time that you need. for example:

```
today = new Date();//2015-24-2
lastYear = today.setMonth(-12);//2014-24-2
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set year to your date object like

longDate.setFullYear(2013);